# Validate that sequence of numbers are within allowed range

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

How can I validate that a sequence of numbers falls into an allowed range of numbers in a more scala/functional (not java like) way?

```
val valuesRight = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val valuesWrong = Seq(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
val allowedValues = Range(1, 8)

def containsNotAllowedValues(allowed: Range, input: Seq[Int]): Boolean = {
  var containsNotAllowedValue = false
  // pseudo code of how to do it in java, But how in scala / functional way?
  while next element is available
    validate if it is contained in allowed
    if not allowed set containsNotAllowedValue to true and break the loop early
  }
  containsNotAllowedValue
}

containsNotAllowedValues(allowedValues, valuesRight) // expected false as no wrong element contained
containsNotAllowedValues(allowedValues, valuesWrong) // expected true as at least single wrong element is contained
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Range(1, 8)` is equivalent to `(1 until 8)`.  i.e. `Range(1, 8).max == 7`  If all you need is a lower/upperbound for the allowed range, a `Tuple` (e.g. `(1, 8)`) might be a simpler choice, as [`Range`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) is for a more general purpose with constructor `Range(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int)`.

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as simple as this:

```
def containsNotAllowedValues(allowed: Range, input: Seq[Int]): Boolean = {
  !(allowed.head <= input.min && allowed.last >= input.max)
}

val valuesRight = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val valuesWrong = Seq(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
val allowedValues = Range(1, 8)

containsNotAllowedValues(allowedValues,valuesRight) //false
containsNotAllowedValues(allowedValues,valuesWrong) //true
```

This will fail if the Range has only 1 value like Range(1,1)
If you want you can add

```
allowed.size>1
```

to catch those cases

Comment: I think you got the results negated. `containsNotAllowedValues(allowedValues,valuesRight)` should return false.

Comment: I like this one, as well as partial matches, are supported. The pre-condition of continuous values is fine for my use case.

Comment: This solution would traverse `input` twice.  Perhaps something like `input.exists(i => i < allowed.min || i > allowed.max + 1)` would be more efficient.

Comment: Why even do math on the indexes yourself when you have `Range.contains`?

Comment: You guys are overcomplicating things just cause

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `forall` function on `Seq`. It checks whether the given predicate is true for all elements in the `Seq`. If that function returns false with the predicate `allowed contains _`, then your `Seq` contains an illegal value.

```
def containsNotAllowedValues(allowed: Range, input: Seq[Int]): Boolean = 
    !input.forall { allowed contains _ }
```

Comment: Though this only works if `all` numbers are matched. Is there something which allows for partial matches?

Comment: What do you mean "partial match"? Do you mean if the `Seq` contains at least 1 of the allowed values?

Comment: If so, then you can do something like `input.exists { allowed contains _ }`

Comment: I mean the opposite if it contains at least one not allowed value.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Yes, that is what my original code does. What do you mean?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Oh, now I see. That's a bug. It was supposed to work. I fixed my answer.